# Output file not being created

Tags: java

I am trying to create an output.txt file, the code is compiling with no errors, but the o/p file is not being created. Any help please?

```
 import java.io.*;

public class StudentPoll_dasariHaritha {

public static void main( String args[] )
 {
int frequency[] = new int[ 6 ];

  try {
 BufferedInputStream pollNumbers =
 new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( "numbers.txt" ) );

try {
 // for each answer, use that value as subscript to
 // determine element to increment
while( true ) {
        ++frequency[ pollNumbers.read() ];
     }
 }

 catch( EOFException eof ) {
  }

 String output = "Rating\tFrequency\r\n";

 // append frequencies to String output
 for ( int rating = 1; rating < frequency.length; rating++ ) {
        output += rating + "\t" + frequency[ rating ] + "\r\n";
     }



 BufferedWriter writer =
 new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( "output.txt" ) );
 writer.write( output );
 writer.close();



 pollNumbers.close();

 System.exit( 0 );

 }

 catch( IOException io ) {

   System.exit( 1 );
   }
```

Can someone explain me y this code is not creating the output text file?

Comment: `catch(IOException io) { System.exit(1); }` - you're ignoring errors. At least do something like `catch(IOException io) { io.printStackTrace(); System.exit(1); }`.

Comment: i was not getting errors when i compile, but just not creating the output txt file.

Comment: It won't give *compile-time* errors. If you don't add `printStackTrace` you wouldn't know about any *runtime* errors.

Comment: i did add printStackTrace but there isn't any change... please help me out..

Comment: I ran those 3 lines where you create the output file and it created it successfully. You're probably not looking in the correct directory (where you ran the program from) for the file.

Comment: iam looking in the same directory where all he src code , and the input txt(numbers.txt) file is located actually the project folder is located on the desktop itself, i can't locate it there. Sorry, iam very new to Java.Can you let me know if i need to look any where else.

Comment: Your code is throwing an exception on my machine, are you even looking at the command-line output?

Comment: yes but i am not having any exception on my machine, iam using netbeans...

Comment: Just a suspicion, but "numbers.txt" hints it is a text file, but using _InputStream.read()_ you are reading its content as single bytes, and then using those to index your array - of 6 elementes - perhaps you want to read the file as text - and check said text for numbers to be interpreted?

Comment: @HarithaDasari I'm also running NetBeans, and I can assure you that there is **absolutely no input** which won't throw an exception (at least on Java 6 or 7). See my answer.

Comment: how do i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The code is throwing exceptions, you're not looking at the command-line output.

1. You need to change your read to something like:

   ```
   int i = pollNumbers.read();
   while (i != -1) {
       ++frequency[i];
       i = pollNumbers.read();
   }
   ```
2. `frequency` probably isn't big enough. If only numbers 0-5 can appear in the file, change your read to: (you also need to ignore anything not in this range, since there is also newline characters and such)

   ```
   ++frequency[i-'0'];
   ```

   This needs to be done because '0', according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), has an integer value of hex 30 = 48, and you want it to instead have an integer value of 0.
3. Remove:

   ```
   catch( EOFException eof ) { }
   ```

   it doesn't seem to do anything.
4. Change your last `catch` to:

   ```
   catch( IOException io ) {
     io.printStackTrace();
     System.exit( 1 );
   }
   ```

   otherwise you're just ignoring errors.

Comment: Thanks for you help Dukeling, i did made all the changes as u said, but even then the output txt file is not created.Is it ok to use BufferedWriter or do i need to use PrintStreamer?

Comment: @HarithaDasari I can speculate as to what is wrong, but it's much easier if you just look at the output window in NetBeans (typically at the bottom of the screen), which you probably weren't doing if you didn't see the previous errors (and learn to debug). When I ran the original code, I saw [this](http://i.imgur.com/t9K2ibo.png). There's nothing wrong with `BufferedWriter`.